# Option parskip reduces section width

Tags: koma-script

Source:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]{}{}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}
\section*{Foo \hfill 1 January 1970}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer
id, vulputate a, magna.
\end{document}
```

Renders to:

[image: Layout without option parskip]

With `\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook}`, title width is reduced:

[image: Layout with option parskip]

*How do I have paragraphs separated by vertical space without affecting title
 width?*

Comment: You can use `parskip=full-` with a minus at the end. Then `\parfillskip` will be set to 0.

Comment: Addition: The problem disappears if you remove titlesec as scrbook defines `\section` so that it locally resets `\parfillskip`.

Comment: Right, I should probably change `section*` styling the Koma script way. This is for a collection of letters, kind of like a diary, with one letter per section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage of `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. You could use the possibilities of KOMA-Script:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1sp]{section}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\raggedsection{}

\begin{document}
\section*{Without parskip\hfill1 January 1970}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer
id, vulputate a, magna.

\KOMAoptions{parskip}

\section*{With parskip\hfill1 January 1970}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer
id, vulputate a, magna.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I have used `afterskip=1sp` because only a positive value results in a vertical skip. If the value is `0pt` or negative a run-in heading is activated and the absolute value results in a horizontal skip.

Comment: Why do you use `afterskip=1sp` instead of for example `afterskip=0pt`?

Comment: @feklee See my updated answer.